VS Code MUI and other library imports suggestions not working. (REACT | MUI | JAVASCRIPT)
In vs-code imports used to work but they stopped working and when I try to import something I doesn't get any suggestions.
I tried looking into settings of VS code doesn't find much there and tried some other things like extensions updates/removal/installation.
Also googled it a bit could not find exact solution

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I posted this question as I was facing the issue for last couple of days and solution is:
I tried multiple things like:

Checking editor settings (settings.json) but it was fine
Also tried updating, removing and installing again the extensions and it was also not the issue

At last I realised I have been using the node modules from quite a long time and haven't removed them was just doing npm install.
Solution: I removed node modules folder and also package-lock.json file and then reinstalled the packages using npm install or npm i and it seems to work again, so it was packages cache on my local.
Hope my experience helps someone, thanks!!

You can accept your answer now
